# How to reduce PostgreSQL max_connections parameter in Greenplum?

Tags: greenplum

I am installing Greenplum DB and every time I try to initialize, i get a semaphore error that says

```
could not create semaphores: No space left on device
```

I have increased the values in `/etc/sysctl.conf` but I still keep getting the errors.
Does anyone know what am missing or know where I can reduce the max connections in Greenplum to get past this?

Comment: According to [the manual](http://docs.greenplum.org/5160/admin_guide/topics/g-connection-parameters.html) it's the same as in Postgres: `max_connections` which apparently can be changed using [gpconfig](http://docs.greenplum.org/5160/admin_guide/topics/g-setting-a-local-configuration-parameter.html)

Comment: Did you set the semaphores based on the install guide on all nodes in the cluster?

Comment: I copied all the config files from the manual

Comment: Please also reload the sysclt.conf file once you changed it. Alternatively, reboot the server.